# Can you cast non self spells from Meld into Stone?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, familiars, rituals

The clause in [Meld Into Stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/meld-into-stone) that says "you [...] can cast spells on yourself..." is confusing, because it doesn't say with a range of Self or if the rationale is because you are behind full cover.

Some spells can take origin without clear line of sight. For example, [find familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) makes it come into existence within a range of 10 feet. Does Meld Into Stone also disallow touch spells like [magic stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-stone) that can be delivered via a familiar?

Many DM interpret the Meld Into Stone spell as only meaning self range spells, but an alternative interpretation could mean that the spells are on yourself due to the requirement of needing a clear path to a target. If that isn't required due to a find familiar touch delivery mechanism or a touch spell on yourself or a spell that summons a creature within 10 feet of you that does not require sight, how is one supposed to know which is the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You can cast any spell that targets yourself

Meld into Stone says:

> You remain aware of the passage of time and can **cast spells on yourself** while merged in the stone. You can use your movement to leave the stone where you entered it, which ends the spell. You otherwise can't move.

The spell says you can cast spells on yourself, it does not limit you to spells with range Self. There are many spells you can cast on yourself that do not have a Range of self, for example touch spells. The PHB spellcasting rules on p. 201 say under targeting yourself:

> If a spell targets a creature of your choice, you can choose yourself, unless the creature must be hostile or specifically a creature other than you. If you are in the area of effect of a spell you cast, you can target yourself.

Any such spell can be cast, as long as it targets yourself.

Note that *magic stone* is not targeting yourself though, it is targeting one to three pebbles you would touch. So you would not be able to cast that one, even if you could deliver it with your familiar -- you can only cast spells on yourself.